# Automatically exporting baked textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export, texture-baking

I have quite a bit of baking to do, so was wondering if there's a way to automatically export the textures after they're done baking?

I'm using Blender 2.79b

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. I'm using an add-on called "Bake All" and somehow missed the "Auto Save images" tick box.

Comment: Don't let lack of answers discourage you from asking more questions. Sometimes, users respond a day or two later.